Explanation for chain-weight GDP growth
I am currently learning about how real GDP growth is calculated, and I am confused by the motivation for the chain-weight method of calculating it. To calculate the chain-weight real GDP growth from year $t$ to $t+1$, one calculates the fixed-weight real GDP with year $t$ as the base year, calculates the same quantity using year $t+1$ as the base year, and then takes the geometric mean of the two to arrive at one plus the chain-weight GDP growth.
My understanding is that the fixed-weight method, where a base year is fixed and the prices that year are used for weights when calculating real GDP in subsequent years, faces the problem of the weights no longer being relevant to the year of interest, seeing as relative prices can change. Should we not, then, use $t+1$ as the base year, always, since the weights there are the most relevant? Why need we average it with the fixed-weight GDP growth using year $t$ as the base year when calculating chain-weight growth? And why do we use the geometric mean instead of the arithmetic mean?
In other words, to find out the real GDP growth from years $t$ to $t+1$, can we not simply agree to always use the fixed-weight real GDP based at year $t+1$, i.e.,
$$
\%Y_{t\to t+1} = \frac{Y(t+1)_{FWt+1} - Y(t)_{FWt+1}}{Y(t)_{FWt+1}}
$$
and then have the real GDP be calculated as
$$
Y(t+1)=Y(t)(1+\%Y_{t\to t+1})
$$
with some year chosen to be equal to its nominal GDP?
